# PHP and multi threading

Tags: php

I was wondering. If you have a PHP request and the PHP code calls a command line tool via `exec`..

Is the command line then processed in another thread than the one the PHP script is running under?

And if so are both shared over more than one core?

Comment: Was just about to answer when I noticed clarkk's comment...

Comment: @obe just flag the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [manual suggests](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

This might give you an idea that the process is not forked and runs on the main thread. PHP actually waits for the output to end and get the last line of the log.

However, there is a way to run your command in background:

```
nohup MY_COMMAND > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!
```

Since `exec` receives the value of the last line of the output, this will return the `pid` of the process and you will be able to `kill` it later on.

---

Also, as N.B. mentioned in a comment, you may use [`fastcgi_finish_request()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) function if you use fpm - FastCGI Process Manager.

That function gives the client an answer without stopping the script execution. For instance, this is how you send an e-mail without `fpm`:

```
mail($recipient, 'Subject', 'Hello, Kitty!');
echo 'Okay, we sent the e-mail';
```

And this is how you may send an email with `fpm`:

```
echo 'Okay, we sent the e-mail';
fastcgi_finish_request();
mail($recipient, 'Subject', 'Hello, Kitty!');
```

In this case the client will get the echoed text and the `mail` function will still run in the background.

Just do not forget to close your sessions with `session_write_close();` before you use `fpm` ;)

Comment: There's also `fastcgi_finish_request()` available for `php-fpm` users, which sends the response back to server and everything after that function continues to run in the background (sort of). Any chance you could mention it in your answer? I don't want to pollute the thread with yet another answer that contains only this information.